# QR code to image

Tags: javascript

I've done a lot of searching around for this but to no avail.

I have a system where users purchase event tickets. On each event ticket is a code, which is used to generate a QR code (users need to be checked into the venue with this using a scanner).

Generating the QR code on the site is not a problem, but I need to get this into an email. I'm using http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ and obviously emails can't generate the QR code from this. so essentially I need to create an image, save it on the server, and then have the email link to it.

How can I create an image from the Javascript generated QR code?

Thank you

Comment: Don't create images on the client side. Create them server sided (for example there ready-to-use solutions for php) and retrieve those images by javascript (if you have to) doing an https call (ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the qr code and save the image using this php code:
http://joserobinson.com/blog/como-generar-qr-codes-con-php/

Then, send the email with the attached image.